# How to Use Multiple Role's In twig (Symfony2)

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1, roles

**I am having these 3 role's**

```
1. ROLE_ADMIN
2. ROLE_SAMPLE
3. ROLE_USER
```

**This My twig file**

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
    <a href="...">Delete</a>
{% endif %}
```

i need to show the delete link for ROLE_ADMIN and also ROLE_SAMPLE
how do i get it????
above code is to show the delete link for only **ROLE_ADMIN** 
how to add one more role(**ROLE_SAMPLE**) in that???

Comment: Note that you need to check this inside your delete functionality code as well. Did you try above with `if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SAMPLE')` or `if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') OR is_granted('ROLE_SAMPLE')` // may be 'or', '|', '||'

Comment: it's work...thank's for Your help....    {% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or is_granted('ROLE_SAMPLE') %}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

see this link: [Symfony2 and Twig sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624433/symfony2-and-twig-sidebar?rq=1)

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') or is_granted('ROLE_SAMPLE') %}
        <a href="...">Delete</a>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 11):

At least as of Symfony 3.2.8 you can use an array to list roles. So this should work:

```
{% if is_granted(['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_SAMPLE']) %}
    <a href="...">Delete</a>
{% endif %}
```

I don't know when this was added, but I prefer it to using multiple calls with or.

Comment: To clarify, as I understand the [source code](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/4.3/Authorization/Voter/Voter.php#L41), passing an array of roles means that you grant access if *any* of them is granted (as opposed to *all* them). I found this confusing and cannot find any mention of this in the doc.

Comment: Passing an array to is_granted has been deprecated in Symfony 4 and removed in Symfony 5 (see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/37132), so this answer isn
t valid anymore.